# See jobs running from running a script (Unix)

Tags: unix, sed, sh, jobs

I can't find this question anywhere, although it's such a simple thing. Is there a way of seeing jobs running that come from reading a script?

For:

```
command 1 &
command 2
```

jobs tells me which tasks are running and which are finished. This does not work when I create the commands on fly with sed and use sh to run them.

Example:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\t\(.*\)/ echo "\1" >> Families6\/\2 \& /g ' myfile.txt | sh

jobs
```

Comment: What exact information do you need from `jobs`? You can see all the active processes by using the `ps` command, does this give enough information?

Comment: Hey. I would like knowing exactly how many tasks remain to be finished and which are finished already. That is the "job" of the jobs command, but it doesn't give any information in my case.

Comment: If you know `pid` of the process/shell that spawned them, you can use `ps` (with any formatting you like) and apply parent pid filter `--ppid`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `sed` like this. Just start the children in your current shell with something like

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r str outfile; do
    echo "$str" >> Families6/"$outfile" &
done < myfile.txt
```

Then `jobs` will show you the active jobs. Note, however, that the "jobs" you show in the example are so trivial that it will probably take longer to fork the subshell that runs them than to actually run the command. Just run them serially in the foreground without `&`, or use `awk`:

```
awk -F $'\t' '{print $1 >> Families6/$2}' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wrote an example with echo, but actually I use a custom function specific for Biology (seq_extract), hence requiring sed (or that while loop you specified). 
 It's 100 jobs and some of them take 10 minutes while others take 2 hours. I know that if I copied the results of this sed command and pasted them in the shell, then jobs would give the expected output when written. I guess

Comment: This is a classic example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to solve a problem that you think requires `sed`, so you ask about your `sed` solution instead of asking about the actual problem.